# JNI getmethodID returns NULL only in ICS but not in Gingerbread

Tags: android, java-native-interface, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I'm currently porting Gingerbread code to ICS. The communication between C and Java happens properly in Gingerbread. But the same thing crashes in ICS. Not able to figure out.

What are the major changes in ICS jni.?

My current problem,

1.Get the Class Instance and convert it into global reference and store it.

```
  jclass myWrapperClass = (*env)->FindClass(env,"com/test/mypackage/Wrapper");

  if (voipWrapperClass == NULL) {

   // error - handling and returns

  }

  WrapperClass = (jclass)(*env)->NewGlobalRef(env,myWrapperClass);
```

2.From a JNI call the flow goes to below stack and returns callback to jni. From JNI to java the below function call

```
  void response(void* ptr, int result){

  JNIEnv *envPtr= NULL;

  JavaVM* vmPtr= p_pdb->vm;

  if ((*vmPtr)->GetEnv(vmPtr,(void**) &envPtr, JNI_VERSION_1_4) == JNI_EDETACHED) {

      (*vmPtr)->AttachCurrentThread(vmPtr,(void**)&envPtr,NULL);

  }

  if (ptr->WrapperClass == NULL) {

      // error- handling and return   
  }

  RespMethodId = (*envPtr)->GetMethodID(envPtr,ptr->WrapperClass, "resp","(Z)V");

  // this method is always 0 ... prev for gingerbread it returned a valid id..

  }
```

Please give me a solution how to proceed further.?

Comment: One thing I can see wrong is 'WrapperClass = (jclass)(*env)->NewGlobalRef(env,WrapperClass);
'. Shouldnt it be NewGlobalRef(myWrapperClass) instead

Comment: possible duplicate of [ICS - JNI getmethodID returns NULL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772645/ics-jni-getmethodid-returns-null)

Comment: @jogabonito ya sorry.. i changed t too..  but still it returns 0...

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution finally. I used to compile my code in android code-base (2.3.3) but from ICS if you need to build a separate shared library use NDK and build a separate library. Else place the code in frameworks folder. This solves the problem. :)